# VueJS - using v-bind to pass an attribute supplied by a webservice

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I started to work recently on a VueJS project (first time with that framework) and I face a problem.

I have an object (called "propObject") defined in a mother component. That propObject gets its value via a webservice, called in a beforeRouteEnter method in that mother component.

I have to pass this propObject to a child component so I can display what's inside (a "libelle" attribute, among other things). I tried to do it using v-bind and props but I didn't manage to make it work.

Here is my code :

**Mother.vue**

```
<template>
<div class="row justify-content-center">
  <b-container>
     <b-row>
    {{propObject.libelle}}
       <b-col> <cpm-child :prop-object="propObject"/></b-col>
       [...]
     </b-row>
  </b-container>
</template>
<script lang="ts" src="./mother.component.ts"></script>
```

**Mother.component**

```
@Component({
  components: {
    'cpm-child': Child,
  },
})

export default class Mother extends Vue {
    @Inject('propObjectService') private propObjectService: () => propObjectService;

    public propObject: IPropObjectClass = new PropObjectClass();

    beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
    next(vm => {
        if (to.params.propObjectId) {
          vm.load(to.params.propObjectId);
        }
      });
    }

    public load(propObjectId: string): void {
    this.propObjectService()
      .find(propObjectId)
      .then(res => {
        this.propObject = res;
      });
    }
}
```

**Child.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
     <span>
    {{propObject.libelle}}
    [...]
     </span>
  </div>
</template>
<script lang="ts" src="./child.component.ts"></script>
```

**Child.component**

```
export default class Child extends Vue {
  props: {
    propObject: IPropObjectClass,
  }  
}
```

**propObject.model.ts**

```
export interface IPropObjectClass {
  code?: string;
  libelle?: string;
  [...]
}

export class PropObjectClass implements IPropObjectClass {
  constructor(
    public code?: string,
    public libelle?: string,
    [...]
  ) {}
}
```

My goal is to display the {{propObject.libelle}} in the child vue. In the Google Chrome's console, propObject is considered "undefined".

Last information : {{propObject.libelle}} is displayed correctly in the mother vue after a few seconds, so the propObjectService works as intended.

So far, nothing I tried worked, so any help would be greatly appreciated. If you need further clarification, don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Please create a [mcve] with some dummy data. You can use built in snippet or codesandbox

Comment: Seems like you're mixing syntaxes, surprised you're not getting an error in your IDE.  Your prop should be defined with a decorator if you're using the class syntax e.g. `@Prop({ required: true }) readonly propObject!: IPropObjectClass;`

Comment: Thank you very much, @Steven B. ! Replacing my prop declaration with a class syntax's one allowed me to declare the data() methods properly.

Answer (score 1):

I created a sample with Vue 2 / Vue CLI showing a standard way of initializing a prop with data before rendering the child.  You should be able to port it to your app.

The main takeaways are that you can call your data service in the parent (Mother) `created()` lifecycle hook.  And by using the `v-if` directive, you child will not be rendered until the prop has been updated with data from the service call.

Parent.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="parent">
    <h4>Parent</h4>
    <hr>
    <child v-if="user" :userProp="user"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import axios from 'axios'
  import Child from './Child.vue'

  export default {
    components: {
      Child
    },
    data() {
      return {
        user: null
      }
    },
    methods: {
      getUser() {
        axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1')
          .then(response => this.user = response.data)
          .catch(error => console.log(error));
      }
    },
    created() {
      this.getUser();
    }
  }
</script>
```

Child.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="child">
    <h5>Child</h5>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-3 font-weight-bold">ID</div>
          <div class="col-md-5">{{ user.id }}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-3 font-weight-bold">NAME</div>
          <div class="col-md-5">{{ user.name }}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-3 font-weight-bold">USER NAME</div>
          <div class="col-md-5">{{ user.username }}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-3 font-weight-bold">EMAIL</div>
          <div class="col-md-5">{{ user.email }}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: {
      userProp: {
        type: Object,
        required: true
      }
    },
    data() {
      return {
        user: this.userProp
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```